# Regular expression for selecting text with specific start and end strings, and also excluding specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

Say, I have the following strings:

```
const { user } = props;
const { task } = state;
const { words } = response;
const { plays } = result;
```

and I want to select the strings that

- start with "const {"
- end with ";"
- but do not contain the words, "props" or "state"

I reached this point

`(?<=const\s)(.*)(?=;)`

which helps me select the content within the desired start/end. But I'm unable to figure out how to exclude the words, intended for exclusion.

How can I get

```
// Expected output 1
user } = response
user } = result
```

Further, how can I get

```
// Expected output 2
const { user } = response;
const { user } = result;
```

I intend to run a similar regex patterns on files, using NodeJS/javascript.

Comment: `(?<=const\s)(.*)(?=;)` matches any zero or more chars between `const`+whitespace till the rightmost `;` on the same line. What you want to do is to skip parts of the string in between which is impossible with any regex. You should think of a workaround.

Comment: Are you really coding in JavaScript or are you editing JS code from VSCode using Find and Replace?

Comment: First, I'm using Find/Replace in VSCode, and then I want to write code in nodejs that can run that pattern on files

Comment: Then it is your second problem, you should actually think of how you can work around the limitation using JavaScript means. Forget about Visual Studio Code, it is not a regex editor, and it won't help you handle this task.

Comment: If you have to use a regex, you might try to extract those substrings you described in the requirements and then simply replace all between `{...}` with the word `user`: `text.match(/const\s(?:(?!props|state).)*;/g).map(x => x.replace(/{[^{}]*}/, '{ user }'))`

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: Please remove this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(?<=const\s)(.*)(?=;)` current pattern matches any zero or more chars between `const` and a whitespace till the rightmost `;` occurrence on the same line. What you want to do is to skip parts of the string in between, which is impossible to achieve with a regex. You should always think of a workaround in these cases. That is, you either replace using capturing groups in the pattern and backreferences in the replacement (if you need to get a single match), or change the whole logic altogether (when you need multiple matches, like here).

In this case, you may extract all strings that you currently match, make sure there are no words you do not want to appear on the matched lines, and then replace all strings between curly braces with the `{ user }` string (that is deduced from your required outout).

Then you can use something like

```js
const text = "const { user } = props;\nconst { task } = state;\nconst { words } = response;\nconst { plays } = result;"
console.log(
    text.match(/const\s(?!.*\b(?:props|state)\b).*;/g).map(x => x.replace(/{[^{}]*}/, '{ user }'))
)
```

Output:

```js
[
  "const { user } = response;",
  "const { user } = result;"
]
```